# How to change a function's parameter type based on the current input?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

i want to do something like trpc does on the `router.query` and `router.mutation` methods.

i have a method called `createProcedure` that accepts an object with 2 props:

- one is a validation `schema`
- other is a `resolver`, that receives an object with the output of the validated schema (the property name is `input`)

and returns a function that accepts an object with the same signature as the `resolver`.

i want the resolver to hint the `input` property only if a schema is provided.
i want the returned function to allow an `input` property only if the procedure has a defined schema.

here is a [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhACgJwPYFsCWBnCAHgBUA+KAXimKgB8p1t8iyBuAKAgA8wM1gooSA0wBjCABMArmggBRAG4QAdgKpTlEiADMcyyR269+g8NEbjpsmDgkSANhADucWZSgAKCEtUAuERiWMvI+wACUlOQKGLYcOFjGAgDeAF4ANFAAWhgScmiYaAC+UNqYWFAA5Ck5FRzs2hqiwDgYylCisnDAqGKSwYQAyqIAFhBYcFDc3Zp4UCkAdNkSxGYAgsogGQDyUsBgu+7RtqQeGGDAeP5J7FBQeCNjcAD8-kOj4xy3uHaOLrIvASC1lsDmcrggnygsjwGHsSn8p3Olyg11utz0+2AAIWem0EDQgwe41IkNu3hUwH8Fj6skUFMhhQiFHI8CQPSYBEIOz2uxJ7EZCLOFyuUAxu2x81x+MJ7zgJMmoSpvSsIQpUEZkVgCGQjFwnJudBRBrRdykonEeGRwDQUghxrREi6cH83MxpPVBvoqJNpvNEEt-m0cHsBHdZPyfH8CyWADE+ONgN1chGCTjlHiCW9HqQ+SbCuxyN7ZMAZG04HgQMpRJ5HcA4EzC-ahNAAGrB2xdFrKPIFdzRnJxtAJpM9viENMZmXZvn2nDaTxCvDze6yqAAMjXUFrcElykxlAo6k0Oj0kgi3pNwGGmCcUH0t9HaA8ACIAJJ7g74KEQACOUhwsgSPMz5hO6+azvOHgAISLsuRITBuW5Oru+5QYeUAaFouj6BI572rcV43nezhQI+L7vvuygYAIRgQE0kjAaB9rgSasHfKCfwQE88weNu8zkqoTH2o4AhgK4BASFG8wDHAeIoOJEAAEoQCWaDKCskBTuMGQTtKWbEuQVAXmieBmhaVo2hAaT4Uhdb+HxYrANZeZ1Cac4LkicGynhPpQGJaASe4cAuDgAiwSujzLrJqAKasFZVrxyGOUxebsBBnhQf5EnLmZ-p4D5PqiK0eACNo8ZdEm7hZQx+IFPMZVDl0HgROWUBtvYHbNK0j6uT6xalkavm3KZfoBiUwYEM5Q21ZGJTlYmkhTS5zFpZeaAgINfUqQNxkmiN5n+NatpLT627+MFcChVAsHQrCSgeLtPoCZStk7s9J2+Y5-jhfBUBPH5ClAduUD+JhJ44R9aKMpDhRge0XQjJ4EAFW5kHQHoJVwFWEAYPOSyPijW2qW0j17blY1BiGVk2SaM1oP4ED1fNzVQK17WdV2j6Q7csM2fmqX2v1ambWTo0WcdNlnazIVhZ5t1whAiV1mEJ28zzHDgUVyglRhBBoNSKqzEZBp4DgADmyjvv4HQQF07JAorxkReMUkYIgABWdHAA9NOTOMOD2FJJVoHoZvNfx-v2M13MA5aTh8JJczLtaofNcxKuC-6d0QOd8XVg9jkasyIs+gA9KXopQC4qiCBg35YBgSiCKMUAAAZg9hkityUZTN+jH5OVAvvl3cejiJXNt2xIrN3L9DXN1+YDKsEq1DULJO+7Tkf+I53GPAHvv81DBrQwaiD2FjADW1udN0BvBD7vny-CnhJIXDYlyaI84FXWMCFe0BW6OW7kvM4tcoDICgGbVoVkh5DSgCPU22NK4SFsDXSe3QZ7OwmPPK8i9l6yD5ifMI-I6iIPNm0PQfkCHQGGK1PQ3R7AdQINraAuCW6OVMJAdgWsdamwtpId8ABVPWQUZa63xPfaEy4KHvkfmiZ6oNjydwkCdL6n8FHb0qBUGOYk44J38BUCoK1GRpXch4fhOFhF6xymLQmvDYSM3sBgMOljBHKBEfieYfF972BIV-Cu8CgnBIAHphPhm0SBHdTzT2QKIOAUgCDXXnAA0UA8uEQHtCPVofdR4W3fNQwINJYGIE-AIPAwwMBSHsBIVQ-JJhUxLg4xw8xnGuIoe4zxaB+Ipgjpdew3EAD6dN8pZMCcEiZYSQmTBTBk2Y4Iq58EvqHdofBZBNHsCAfkaVEmSJoUuc+V95FkkVBhZRMS1ED0McYgJUApkoNaAIau-8OHpNAWAcBcAwCQFcFAUYbg4kJKSXg2YoCHZbgwP6O81Exl-LgE3CY2Ctzg0kPyMIQA) with my attempt on getting it done, and also pointing the issues that i had.

edit 1:
here is a [ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLwDRwFoQCYFEpTRwC+cAZoSHAETI7UDcAUEzAJ5gCmcAsgIZsARpwAKlYAGdOAHgAqAPjgBeOLLgAfOGIghJMhc04APSLDjsuWwgGNO2AK5ROuAG6cAdvBX332TmWB3O0MTaHgLbm1bByceYGxsABtOAHc+J2U4AApON08ALisIaMdnPJgASmVFFwh45lYObgARYDIyTidPAHkwGAlpAGVrAAtOED44YxgPbAkUADosbFkmgEF3NnRu+xgwXcza+MUVBCY4OAlR8b4AfkKfPwCg7GYL3QTktKd7opLY+JJVLpThvOBOCQQRJuQpZCB9CSFM4XC6BfYwX6PfyBYLnFG5DwwQpROylVyEsHEKpKRT8ISicRSaQ7Pa7eTMUiaZGXa4TQrDMYTMEfIHfTi-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-XAiN8MjcDFYq0KcFkj0QYtRIufjAeO3hAOFKj9m3HAXMZa5cAPD5OLYKHwMVKnJA5euwajNknD06Tef4czfCSZwEBk8skUFxbJ3y374G2295AtlIGfgVrhScHzbNCy78xixL6mRe3mdNdh9HGxcltrn7TcFh9xYZ87rvu57r1Kj7DeUYHC3lKP4cezZkMTHA0f-fFidPMnGdUqHhtYTWTCM+4zO1VIUCSqU8ynFmwAAObuDioUDcnAtxfycL7M0J8KyLAgIIAAVpwJcUDEI3GAIkbszMoCBH-kLBY6DEhCwzutfMKRoBbUWNg3BQsxrpzNF7ZUYkJJSTxrJao1sUQAHouFBxDAlMKrUXabCniiGenCO4TAwYUAGs1CHjyNlhehFxBCJFLgAaxAZuGYECt4MI3t7WErk5JNR4XwyYkhBGhVLmwRRJAKhMENkwMxEgAFrkCDHK0Uo4AjBFoEGYiRxZSFftwfmzVuAA3ME0Z+TN4CuMAXYOKABVD+CMkbwHsB-XREhbJuLiqgneV84J2H1ofAKhDCgAHJKmh1IRIchUBKHVLxF6KkLB8rxJeMkj+1MXr5hri-SEyQFiJAgHgzpiT3ApM6AsBaUjEgOPAmYiiKzVkAD0NlTHmQI3q1iRGkE4GrThgyoTd1GeMtxkzplQAIaOG5hDZoAH0tZ0zNMs1ZHyNlrKmHcqJXB5ggjgA09RuD1zQCcEuRItjcqZM6NkhYqiNEFM1haWqScXih0Ps0pZvCvmXGXIEy4IxWqgvsGASizUID2H-iMSCLl4iCPgNfF4LseT2TCUFSxYAvGlEcQ4oAA) with an attempt using union types

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to change a function's parameter type based on the current input. You need to use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

Classically, I use a type property to switch between union types easily.

```
type InputProps = {
    type: "text"
    text: string;
} | {
    type: "date";
    date: Date;
} | {
    type: "color";
    color: Color;
};
```

But in your case, it is still possible to have types that don't have to share a property. Here is the complete example that uses undefined to do the type check.

```
type DifferentProps = {
    event: number;
} | {
    event?: undefined;
    input: number;
};
function acceptDifferent(props: DifferentProps) {
    if (props.event === undefined) {
        console.log(props.input); // number: number
    } else {
        console.log(props.event); // event: number
    }
}
// valid
acceptDifferent({input: 1})
// valid
acceptDifferent({event: 2})
// invalid
acceptDifferent({event: 3, input: 4})
```

Edit to answer the edit. [Here is the example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLwDRwFoQCYFEpTRwC%20cAZoSHAETI7UDcAUEzAJ5gCmcAsgIZsARpwAKlYAGdOAHgAqAPjgBeOLLgAfOGIghJMhc04APSLDjsuWwgGNO2AK5ROuAG6cAdvBX332TmWB3O0MTaHgLbm1bByceYGxsABtOAHc%20J2U4AApON08ALisIaMdnPJgASmVFFwh45lYObgARYDIyTidPAHkwGAlpAGVrAAtOED44YxgPbAkUADosbFkmgEF3NnRu%20xgwXcza%20MUVBCY4cybC6ncIYbGJxnO4CVHxvgB%20Qp8-AKDsZgXXQJZJpJxfIolWLxJKpdKcQFwJwSCCJNyFLIQPoSQpnC4XQL7GAQn7%20QLBZ4XXIeGCFKJ2UquGmI4hVJSKfhCUTiKTSHZ7XbyZikTR4y5ca6vB58J4XKXvQr3d6I4GwsGcCH0mKcOIguFORHI1Ho7JY-q4ylwQm7QrIBaBDpQIZvCZCy3UgqQhlOJmeFlsjkCYTaXS8-lEt3EFgROCtdqdGnNPgwPjO6VTIwzXzzO3LVZcDZbODhg4qI7YE6IZ4SezWWwSHHmKD2BHPbDJviFEswYXPUWWmt1zgNwpkPiJKSIqkEaC2pY4ABi0AmMBmeBnTrtDs6afe8jdFyjTDIPmsMGAEHccGsTmT3OK3pkSomGazc0WefWm22uyJhzqFZZM8ZqNnGjo0r0-S7hMP4CjA8hMBUGKWu2Kb5JaFz9vi2FWu4RIkr4ZL-FOOEerSXrar6PYYSQNFYThBJ4Taizbk6z58AeDFTOUdI2I%20VEkYezwBrwQb3qGMhgQmnhJim0F8LBEaKGKTgwI4V58BIbDuNY2SoXwIlihcMYAGrjvEyYXu4%20CEFAmS5ouy7JmuNnQNIW7uI68n7g02FtKa2ILPKL4AGQhXA%20n2kxXhKN4hF-HYVRGfiMAjIQKRwEEGWuVAWTUAAktFVrzE4ACO9jAE42ALNQFQkUeflkNkACEIFBS6kxhRFHZRX%20zWxXApIJdgSU0al6WZakcA5XlhV-rc8DGFwZ52DVdWWg1%20JtaqoLwh8CxZJFZHrZayTwGA6RSNgc6DHwHQiJdnAAEqcGpUDuPmT4degHleex%206ZMlcq1vWjYwM2nCoDR%20mFJF1owFD2HEL5%20L%20ZigXBQZVYMRdUBXZkfBpMA8BtZjQV3aIj1rFpOmHT18PrUjLCNS1uNXUFIPDhIo0MdYl4SPAZBOaudiZGzq2dLZCxC1AK5ZFUmlwGZiQWeel45Sj2Gqep2NcYOoOjuOUiI1xkuzuQwtribSP1czKVQGwuta69OtA-i%20tc4U4MttbOEw3AhN8MTcBtUaaKcFkbvYWRsM9WRvsMfDhSkx1cAfHA4vVfpcDfPF5LYAn%20KsoXyMbdeyajNknA8zhaPcIEAt8DpnAQE1yw5TXDHa%209Tt65zI7kEbkM0dHG6FJw0vC-LAfzMrqtWTlheHoJtFM5a3dXm7HsD97w8Mf7gfB6Hw7GhHUfcTSscpgs8cj7hRLJxjqfp3DRW578%20clxUvul8vTBHkwLImltK6WnuyXWfN3AC0GlIKAWpSjzFOAOYAABzdwhVCg3k4HeeBThI5jSuDQTG1BC6YznBAQQAArTgZ58FcSmBMYAiQ5wCygIEFB8sb6MMSPLJeGdNISBSNAa6ixWHsPljRYuNEw4mmATpPSHZDJ3wAPTKO6imYqmUIAZSbmwZ4d8N69wYu8JhV8%20C9V2PtExiQ75RgYnYou39LSCESE3AA1pg28MxcFnwIRKGgtx2IkOkSfcOGJ9JKPoao9RkxJBaJ0ZsSRG0KjPFLs8aJEhUFXkCBnPi2o4AjEVoEGYiQVZSCgdwGW5gxj3wOBEZ4kDoGZLQXYQqABVWBBMibwHsLAnxEggpZMKnQ-EMdBp53%20L7JORiGFB2YXAAA5AswuF0GxCKgCIpZG1UkpOeGjZp-x2mwI5kOBsndrz81RBPRIEAOEHNae4DpnQFhHW4Sk7C0T6FfO%20QAPT%20bMphmjbgJL0YeKYE5uDJUaVchYNy7lZIeU8qAN8NxcLmftAA%20mbPG7z8SfO%20QSv5PypgbnFMOAOGR1luPYRcggNCYCJFBbRZ4vTOj9IWC49xIyqQ8XGR-SZlpplbI%20WoolLxzylJeCMbRNL7BgAvleVKEB7AoJGFaCK8QtHwH5aLSYmMLZ2VSnEsAeTSg7JYKyeWQA)

Comment: i tried to do this way but it didnt work, check out the playground link on edit 1 of my question

Comment: @demetrius_mp I fixed your code using the first approach I mentioned in the answer. I added the link to the end of my answer.

Comment: thanks! that works as expected. however, i wonder if there is a way without using `type: 'schema' | 'noSchema'`, because what actually implies that the object has a schema or not, is the presence or not of the `schema` property.